# Using Vue2leaflet directly via <script src=... > import

Tags: vue.js, vue2leaflet

I'm new to JavaScript, I'm trying to add some modern interactivity to parts of the websites I create in Python.
Vue looks quite compelling to me and I'd like to use it **without** node/webpack etc, which I am not familiar with.

Vue website has quite comprehensive description on how to use framework itself by importing it via `<script src=... >`, however I'd like to use also Vue2leaflet package.

I tried adding it to the webpage with `<script src=... >` and then registering components in my script with

```
Vue.component('l-map', Vue2Leaflet.LMap);
Vue.component('l-tile-layer', Vue2Leaflet.LTileLayer);
Vue.component("l-circle", Vue2leaflet.LCircle)
```

I was able to render openStreetMaps with tile layer however I am not able to render l-circle to the map.
Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/b2c1rzfa/14/

Why the circles don't get drawn (for either tried option)?
Is the described importing and registering method of Vue2leaflet components correct?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer on Vue forum, pasting it here for someone else's benefit (thanks skirtle) - everything works fine after amending as described below:

> It’s not a problem with how you’re registering the components.
>
> The main problem is this line:
> `<l-tile-layer :url="ll.url"/>`
> You need to change it to:
> `<l-tile-layer :url="ll.url"></l-tile-layer>`
> Because you’re using an
> in-DOM template it’ll be parsed as HTML by the browser before Vue gets
> anywhere near it. The browser’s parser doesn’t support self-closing
> tags using a trailing />. The result is the tags that follow the
>  will be treated as children rather than siblings.
>
> Once you fix that you’ll get a couple of validation errors because
> your second circle is missing some : prefixes on its attributes.
>
> Then you’ll get an error because you haven’t registered l-popup but if
> you zoom out you’ll see your circles.